# Exponential matrix derivative to find the Hessian matrix of negative binomial regression

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix, matrix-exponential, negative-binomial

I am looking for the hessian matrix of the log likelihood function of negative binomial regression

$$l\left( \cdot \right) =\sum ^{n}_{i=1}y_{i}\ln \left( \dfrac{\alpha \exp \left( x_{i}^{T}\beta \right) }{1+\alpha \exp \left( x_{i}^{T}\beta \right) }\right) -\dfrac{1}{\alpha }\ln \left( 1+\alpha \exp \left( x_{i}^{T}\beta \right) \right) +\ln \Gamma \left( y_{i}+\dfrac{1}{\alpha }\right) -\ln \Gamma \left( y_{i}+1\right) -\ln \Gamma \left( \dfrac{1}{\alpha }\right)$$
In Hilbe (2011)
$$\dfrac{\partial l\left( \cdot \right) }{\partial \beta _{k}}= \sum ^{n}_{i=1}\left( \dfrac{\left( y_{i}-\exp \left( x_{i}^{T}\beta \right) \right) x_{i}}{\left( 1+\alpha \exp \left( x_{i}^{T}\beta \right) \right) }\right)$$

Here i’m confused, where does the derivative take the form of  $x_{i}$ and not $x_{i}^{T}$
$$-\dfrac{\partial ^{2}l\left( \cdot \right) }{\partial \beta \partial \beta ^{T}}=\sum ^{n}_{i=1}\left( y_{i}\alpha +1\right) x_{i}x_{i}^{T}\left( \dfrac{\exp \left( x_{i}^{T}\beta \right) }{\left( 1+\alpha \exp \left( x_{i}^{T}\beta \right) \right) ^{2}}\right)$$
At this point,  I don't understand about derive against $\partial \beta _{k}^{T}$ .
I would be very grateful if you would describe the calculation process. I will also be happy if you recommend books or papers regarding derivatives of the exponential matrix and derive against $\partial \beta _{k}$ or  $\partial \beta _{k}^{T}$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2^2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\S{S^{-1}}
$The Frobenius product $(:)$ is extremely useful in *Matrix Calculus*
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many fruitful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A &= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
It also commutes with the elementwise/Hadamard product $(\odot)$
$$A:\LR{B\odot C} = \LR{A\odot B}:C\\$$

---

For typing convenience, define the variables (all functions are element-wise)
$$\eqalign{
X &= \big[x_1\;\;x_2\;\cdots\;x_n\big] \\
a &= \a\o,\;b=\b,\;w=\frac{\o}{a} \\
z &= X^Tb + \log(a)   &\qiq dz = X^Tdb \\
e &= \exp(z) = \a\exp(X^Tb) &\qiq de = e\odot dz \\
s &= \s(z) = \frac{e}{\o+e} &\qiq \big({\rm Logistic\;function}\big) \\
S &= \Diag s &\qiq ds = \LR{S-S^2} dz \\
Y &= \Diag y,\;W\!=\!\Diag w \\
}$$
The derivative of the Logistic function shown above is
[well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative).

Only the first two terms of the log likelihood expression contain $\b,\,$
therefore create a truncated function
and calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\l &= y:\log(s) - w:\log(\o+e) \\
d\l &= y:\fracLR{ds}{s} - w:\fracLR{de}{\o+e} \\
 &= y:\LR{\S ds} - w:\fracLR{e\odot dz}{\o+e} \\
 &= y:\LR{I-S}\c{dz} - w:S\:\c{dz} \\
 &=\BR{Iy-Sy-Sw}:\c{X^Tdb} \\
 &= X\BR{y-Sy-Sw}:db \\
 &= X\BR{y-Ys-Ws}:db \\
g\;=\; \grad{\l}{b} &= X\BR{y-\LR{Y+W}s} \\
}$$
Next, calculate the gradient of $g$, i.e. the Hessian.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= -X(Y+W)\:ds \\
 &= -X(Y+W)\LR{S-S^2}dz \\
 &= -X(Y+W)\LR{S-S^2}X^Tdb \\
H= \hess{\l}{b} \;=\;\grad{g}{b} &= -\c{X}(Y+W)\LR{S-S^2}\c{X^T} \\
}$$
Notice that the terms sandwiched between $X$ and $X^T$ are diagonal matrices, therefore $H$ is symmetric (as it should be).

Some people are overly pedantic and write $(\p b^2)$ as $(\p b\:\p b^T)$ which properly conveys the shape of the Hessian matrix.

---

As for book recommendations, the standard text is probably
Magnus and Neudecker's *Matrix Differential Calculus*,
although personally I prefer
Hjorungnes's *Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives*.

For simply looking up formulas, if you cannot find it online in
Petersen and Pedersen's [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)
then consult
Bernstein's *Matrix Mathematics: Theory, Facts, and Formulas*.

Comment: thank you very helpful, I will read the books.